# Converting matplotlib interpolation plot to Plotly's graphing methods

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, interpolation

I have plotted interpolated data in colourspace to fill and display missing data (temperatures) in an imaginary office space between sensor locations.

The notebook implementation was to see if this could be done in the first place. Now I want to add interactivity in the form of a range slider to see differences in data over time. This means I'll have to use Plotly. I'm not very familiar with their library and would like some pointers on how to achieve results similar to the ones displayed below.

I have already asked for help on their forum but to no avail.

```
from scipy.interpolate.rbf import Rbf #Radial basis functions
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



im = plt.imread('C:\\Users\\definitely_not_me\\Downloads\\floor_plan.jpg')

# Create Figure and Axes objects
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Display the image on the Axes
implot = ax.imshow(im)

# Define location of "sensors" on the axes
x = [100, 100, 100, 250, 250, 250, 400, 400, 400]
y = [100, 350, 600, 100, 350, 600, 100, 350, 600]
z = [22, 23, 22, 22, 25, 15, 21, 22, 22] #temperatures

rbf_adj = Rbf(x, y, z, function = 'gaussian')

# Set extent to which colour mesh stretches over
# the underlying image
x_fine = np.linspace(0, 1000, 81)
y_fine = np.linspace(0, 700, 82)

x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x_fine, y_fine)

z_grid = rbf_adj(x_grid.ravel(), y_grid.ravel()).reshape(x_grid.shape)


# plot the pcolor on the Axes. Use alpha to set the transparency
p=ax.pcolor(x_fine, y_fine, z_grid, alpha=0.3)
ax.invert_yaxis() #invert Y axis for X and Y to have same starting point


# Add a colorbar for the pcolor field
fig.colorbar(p,ax=ax)

plt.savefig('heatmap.png')
```

[Here is the resulting output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcj5f.jpg)

I'm aware of their tutorials for [interpolation in 3d](https://plot.ly/python/v3/interpolation-and-extrapolation-in-2d/) and [range sliders](https://plot.ly/python/range-slider/) but the interactions between their graphing library and standard data science python libraries is quite murky to a novice. E.g., what would be the equivalent of pcolor in Plotly? How would scipy's RBF interact with Plotly's figures? Etc. etc.

Comment: what is your expected output? Plotly can output an Html file that allows for interaction, but not a png file.

Comment: Why do you need to use plotly? Just continue using matplotlib and use matplotlib.widgets' Slider.

Comment: @Shenan I'm not looking for a particular type of output. I'd just like for the data to be displayed online in an interactive form.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 
I wasn't sure if I should ask about easier/better ways of going about this in the post. Thanks for giving me the right idea.

 It doesn't necessarily have to be their library. I only need the plot to be interactive and for it to be displayed online.

Comment: For online display of interactive matplotlib graphs you would need a notebook server, while plotly can work on the client side alone.